# Implementing Facebook Login IOS

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-login

I'm trying to follow the facebook developers website's instructions for implementing their login. Step 5 is telling me to add some code to my AppDelegate class, specifically AppDelegate.m (which I don't have, I only have AppDelegate.swift).

This is the code I'm supposed to add:

```
//  AppDelegate.m
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

  [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
  // Add any custom logic here.
  return YES;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 
            openURL:(NSURL *)url 
            options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options {

  BOOL handled = [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
    openURL:url
    sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey]
    annotation:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]
  ];
  // Add any custom logic here.
  return handled;
}
```

If I try putting it into the AppDelegate.swift file I get all sorts of errors, and I'm not finding any good documentation out there to do this properly. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That code in objective-c , you should use swift

```
import FBSDKCoreKit

import FBSDKLoginKit

  func application(_ application: UIApplication,didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
       FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
       return true
  }

  func application(_ app: UIApplication,open url: URL,options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool
  {

    if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
        let sourceApplication: String? = options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String
        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(app, open: url,sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: nil)           

    } 
     return true
  }

  public func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
       return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, open: url as URL!, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation) 
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it! For anyone else struggling going through the facebook documentation, I recommend this youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iSszeW1aH6I as he explains things pretty well